# SQL error getting counts of subscribes and unsubscribes number from 2 tables

Tags: sql, validation, data-manipulation, presto, sql-function

I'm getting an error on this Presto SQL code in subscribes and unsubscribes function and variable names:

```
SELECT
    emailaddress,
    firstname,
    lastnamename,
    role,
    status,
    optindate,
    optinsource,
    optoutdate,
    optoutreason,
    SUM(subscribes) AS total_subscribes,
    SUM(unsubscribes) AS total_unsubscribes
FROM  
    (SELECT
         emailaddress,
         firstname,
         lastnamename,
         role,
         status,
         optindate,
         optinsource,
         optoutdate,
         optoutreason,
         1 as subscribes
     FROM 
         table_subscribes
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
         emailaddress,
         firstname,
         lastnamename,
         role,
         status,
         optindate,
         optinsource,
         optoutdate,
         optoutreason,
         1 AS unsubscribes
     FROM 
         table_unsubscribes) all
GROUP BY
    emailaddress, firstname, lastnamename,
    role, status, optindate, optinsource,
    optoutdate, optoutreason,
```

I would like to get sum of total subscribes and total unsubscribes from each table combined and group by other attributes into resulting table

Comment: which error exactly

Comment: 'Column 'subscribes' cannot be resolved' in the main select statement at the top

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` will only keep the column namaes of the first query, the rest gets lost, so add all columns to both query of the `UNION` and all will be fine

```
SELECT
  emailaddress,
  firstname,
  lastnamename,
  role,
  status,
  optindate,
  optinsource,
  optoutdate,
  optoutreason,
 SUM(subscribes) as total_subscribes,
 SUM(unsubscribes) as total_unsubscribes
FROM(
      SELECT
       emailaddress,
       firstname,
       lastnamename,
       role,
       status,
       optindate,
       optinsource,
       optoutdate,
       optoutreason,
       1 as subscribes,
       0 as unsubscribes
      FROM table_subscribes
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
       emailaddress,
       firstname,
       lastnamename,
       role,
       status,
       optindate,
       optinsource,
       optoutdate,
       optoutreason,
       0 as subscribes,
       1 as unsubscribes
      FROM table_unsubscribes
)all
GROUP BY
emailaddress,
  firstname,
  lastnamename,
  role,
  status,
  optindate,
  optinsource,
  optoutdate,
  optoutreason
```

If you want a totle of all subscribers yyou need, with out `GROUp BY`

```
SELECT
 SUM(subscribes) as total_subscribes,
 SUM(unsubscribes) as total_unsubscribes
FROM(
      SELECT
       emailaddress,
       firstname,
       lastnamename,
       role,
       status,
       optindate,
       optinsource,
       optoutdate,
       optoutreason,
       1 as subscribes,
       0 as unsubscribes
      FROM table_subscribes
     UNION ALL
     SELECT
       emailaddress,
       firstname,
       lastnamename,
       role,
       status,
       optindate,
       optinsource,
       optoutdate,
       optoutreason,
       0 as subscribes,
       1 as unsubscribes
      FROM table_unsubscribes
)all
```

Comment: Thank You. So query works but i think results are bit strange. my second table_unsubscribes have about 763 records but in resulting column 'total unsubscribes' im only seeing '1' in about 63 rows and also i am seeing more '1's in 'total_subscribes' columns and sometime  '1' in both resulting columns and when i do UNION ALL without sum aggregation i get correct numbers in resulting table. I think i am loosing number of Unsubscribes after thus SUM()

Comment: Then you have to examine what you want, a groupby emailadress will give you all emailsdesses as they are unique, you would get all subscfribers, that are stillsubcribet as 1 0 and  if they have unscribed as 1 1, that alone would sufficeebut you will not get a total sum, four that, you need only the SUM cikumns and no GROUP By and all other coumns